# wifi-connection-weak signal

Tags: wi-fi

My provider has a data cap if 5gb. I have a Samsung Acclaim. Before I went with my current provider I had a smart phone and the provider had no data cap and I downloaded videos, pics, ringtones and streaming videos limitlessly. I am now struggling to stay under the 5gb limit every month. I've heard that wifi doesn't count against the 5gb cap but whenever I try and use it I never get a signal that lasts for very long and it's usually a very poor signal. Any advice, tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wifi connections work by talking to a local wireless access point so, basically, you need to be within reach of one.  Public access points can be found in pubs, coffee shops and the like. You may also have one at home.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Android you're using, but here's what you can try - go to SETTINGS > Wireless & Networking > Wi-Fi Settings. In this screen, press the MENU button and then ADVANCED. Click WiFi Sleep Policy and set it to NEVER.

This helps in retaining the WiFi connection.

If you have a weak WiFi signal to begin with, then the best tip is to move your device closer to the WiFi access point to increase signal strength.